# Error: The best overloaded method match for 'ClassData.Add(string, string, int, int, object)' has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#

I have this following errors below I don't know what I'm missing in this or I have to install directive for it. The errors are

```
1. Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.SqlDbType' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?). 

2. cannot convert from 'System.Data.SqlDbType' to 'int'. 

3. The best overloaded method match for 'ClassData.Add(string, string, int, int, object)' has some invalid arguments.

4. The best overloaded method match for 'ClassData.AddNText(string, string, int, int, System.Text.StringBuilder)' has some invalid arguments.
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

```
public bool SaveToDatabase(string mSpname)
{
bool rtVal = false;

try
{
    string Proc_Code = this.ForStatus_Update != 0 ? string.Empty : this.mClsOBR.ListOBR[0].Proc_Code;
    int Type_Code = this.ForStatus_Update != 0 ? 0 : this.mClsOBR.ListOBR[0].Type_Code;

    clsDs = new classDataSource();
    clsDs.Add(mSpname.Trim(), "@pWinBookid", SqlDbType.Int, 4, this.Winbookid);
    clsDs.Add("", "@pNMRNO", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10, this.NMRNO);
    clsDs.Add("", "@Proc_Code", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 7, Proc_Code);
    clsDs.Add("", "@Type_Code", SqlDbType.Int, 4, Type_Code);

    //MsgBox(String.Concat("Proce :", Me.mClsOBR.ListOBR(0).Proc_Code, " Type Code:", Me.mClsOBR.ListOBR(0).Type_Code.ToString))
    StringBuilder sb = GetStreamBulderHL7(this.dtMessage);
    writeMessage(sb.ToString(), true);
    clsDs.AddNText("", "@pHL7Results", SqlDbType.NText, sb.Length, sb);
    clsDs.Add("", "@ImgItemID", SqlDbType.Int, 4, 0);
    clsDs.Add("", "@PatStausUpdate", SqlDbType.Int, 4, this.ForStatus_Update);

    writeMessage(string.Concat("Winbookid :", this.Winbookid, " NMRNO:", this.NMRNO), true);
    writeMessage(string.Concat("Proce :", Proc_Code, " Type Code:", Type_Code.ToString()), true);
    //srDr = clsDs.GetRs("ConnMedicalLab", 0)

    using (SqlDataReader srDr = clsDs.GetRs("IMAGEDB", 0))
    {

    }

    rtVal = true;

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    writeMessage(string.Concat(ex.Source, "Error :", ex.Message));
    ModuleHl7.WriteExeptionLog(ex, "Problem in Saving to SQL  - Called From: SaveToDatabase_Success");
    rtVal = false;
}
return rtVal;
}
```

Comment: you need to explicitly cast the `enum` to `int` like `(int)SqlDbType.Int`

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is quite clear from the error messages that the 3rd parameter type is int, and not SqlDBType

```
clsDs.Add(mSpname.Trim(), "@pWinBookid", SqlDbType.Int, 4, this.Winbookid);
clsDs.Add("", "@pNMRNO", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10, this.NMRNO);
clsDs.Add("", "@Proc_Code", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 7, Proc_Code);
clsDs.Add("", "@Type_Code", SqlDbType.Int, 4, Type_Code);
```

should be

```
clsDs.Add(mSpname.Trim(), "@pWinBookid", Some_Int_Value_Here, 4, this.Winbookid);
clsDs.Add("", "@pNMRNO", Some_Int_Value_Here, 10, this.NMRNO);
clsDs.Add("", "@Proc_Code", Some_Int_Value_Here, 7, Proc_Code);
clsDs.Add("", "@Type_Code", Some_Int_Value_Here, 4, Type_Code);
```